# Don't working solid style icons from Font Awesome, when defined FontLoader for regular style icons

Tags: qt, qml

To make this code working you need to just comment out regular FontLoader. I set right font.family, but it don't change anything. With what this problem can be linked?

To test the code you can donwload fonts [here](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/fontawesome-free-5.2.0-desktop.zip).

**upd.** As @folibis suggested, reason is clashes of FontLoader names: both of them "Font Awesome 5 Free". Set FontLoader.name manually don't give anything, it just can't be referenced by new name. Any ideas for workaround?

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    // Comment out this to make everything working
    FontLoader {
        id: regular
        source: "qrc:/Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf"
    }

    FontLoader {
        id: solid
        source: "qrc:/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf"
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        text: "Icon: \uf5ca"
        font {
            family: solid.name
            pointSize: 30
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your fonts are not accessible there's no way to test it. I can only assume that both the fonts have the same name. Try to assign different names using [FontLoader.name](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html#name-prop).

Comment: @folibis I tried to set FontLoader.name manually, but it's not work even for only solid font. And you are right. Both of them has name "Font Awesome 5 Free".

Comment: I've tested both the fonts and I'm a little discouraged. Both of them look similar ) How do you test that the font you wont is not loaded? I've change it to  `Text {name: font.name}` and I see that the font I need is loaded.

Comment: @folibis They shouldn't be similar. They may have icons with same name, but with different styles. And I can't get umbrella icon from regular font.

I don't mean that font not loaded, but I can't show needed icon from solid font, when regular is loaded. I think that font name clash is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two .otf files have indeed the same name: "Font Awesome 5 Free".

- When a Text uses this family, the text is displayed with the regular version.
- When a Text uses this family **and** defines `font.bold: true` (or `font.weight: Font.Bold`), the text is displayed with the solid version.

The following code shows these different uses:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    FontLoader {
        source: "qrc:/Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf"
    }
    FontLoader {
        source: "qrc:/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf"
    }

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 60
            Text {
            text: "Icon: \uf5ca" + " - The - " + font.family
            font {
                family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
                pointSize: 30
            }
        }
        Text {
            text: "Icon: \uf5ca" + " - The - " + font.family
            font {
                family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
                pointSize: 30
                bold: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 5.9+, in order to using solid version of the `FontAwesome 5 Free`, you need to set `styleName` property as `Solid`:

```
Text {
    font { 
        family: awesomeFontSolid.name; pointSize: 48; 
        styleName: "Solid"     //<--- 
    }
    text: "\uf142"
}
```